# How to integrate JQuery code in grails layout

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a view that is built by composing it with a given layout.Now I find myself having to add jquery code both in the layout AND in the page. Is there a way to embed parts of the layout code inside the page's "document.ready" function? Otherwise I'd have to repeat the layout components related jquery calls in every page that uses it.

Comment: "Now I find myself having to add jquery code both in the layout AND in the page" - Something is wrong then and whatever that is isn't clear from your description.  Whatever is in the layout gets brought into the decorated page.  You should never have to put jquery code (or anything else) in both.